# Catching custom exception thrown from subclass of OncePerRequestFilter in AuthenticationEntryPoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have a JWTAuthFilter that extends `OncePerRequestFilter` where I am validating the token.

The validateToken method throws custom exceptions(CredentialsChangedException and TooManyDevicesException which extend `org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException`)

These exceptions are caught in the filter properly but when they move forward to the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`, the AuthenticationException turns into an `instanceof` `InsufficientAuthenticationException` and the custom error message that I want to return as a response is lost.

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static final String BEARER = "Bearer ";

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtAuthFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    @Value ("${jwt.http.request.header}")
    private String tokenHeader;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {

        final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader(this.tokenHeader);

        String username = null;
        String jwtToken = null;

        if((requestTokenHeader != null) && requestTokenHeader.startsWith(BEARER)) {
            jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
            try {
                username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
                if((username != null) && (SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                                               .getAuthentication() == null)) {

                    UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);


                    if(jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null,
                                                                                userDetails.getAuthorities());
                        usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                             .setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                logger.error("Unable to get username from JWT. ", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                logger.warn("Expired JWT. ", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

```java
@Component
public class JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint , Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = - 8970718410437077606L;

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException e)
                    throws IOException {

        if(e instanceof TooManyDevicesException) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, Constants.TOO_MANY_DEVICES);
        }

        else if(e instanceof CredentialsChangedException) {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, Constants.CREDENTIALS_CHANGED);
        }
        else {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, Constants.JWT_EXPIRED);
        }

    }
}
```

I want to send an appropriate unauthorized response from my filter, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think once you caught the `AuthenticationException` in `JwtAuthFilter`, you should not move forward to the next filter as most probably an `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` will sit in the later part of the filter chain and this filter will configure the current request to be an anonymous user if `SecurityContextHolder` is empty (i.e happen when authentication fail). The `InsufficientAuthenticationException` is most probably due to Spring considers the current request is an anonymous user who access some protected URL or methods.

Instead , once you catch `AuthenticationException` in your `JwtAuthFilter` , you should then call `AuthenticationEntryPoint.commence()` and end the filter chain . This is also how the [`BasicAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/06d3b60947bca3a8462c1abaf00f611e42aedcae/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java#L195) is doing now .

So , I suggest revise the `JwtAuthFilter` to :

```
@Component
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Autowired
  private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;


  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                    throws ServletException, IOException {
         try{

              //validate JWT

          } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
               logger.error(e.getLocalizedMessage());
                SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
                this.authenticationEntryPoint.commence(request, response, e);
                return;
          }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ken,
The problem I am facing is that the AuthenticationException caught in AuthenticationEntryPoint is always an instance of ```InsufficientAuthenticationException``` and I am trying to figure out how to properly send the custom exception from ```JwtAuthFilter``` to ```JwtUnAuthorizedResponseAuthenticationEntryPoint```

Comment: Hi @DhawalV .Okay now. please see my update . Thanks

Comment: It still doesn't work. It still is passing the message from ```InsufficientAuthenticationException``` to the response.

Comment: really ? `InsufficientAuthenticationException` still passed to your customised `AuthenticationEntryPoint` ? I would be surprise  then. Sure `jwtTokenUtil.validateToken` must not throw `InsufficientAuthenticationException`?

Comment: Hi Ken, yeah. It looks like the ```AuthenticationEntryPoint``` is entered once a runtime exception is encountered in any filter and that runtime exception is handled by ```ExceptionTranslationFilter``` which in my case is converting ```AuthenticationException``` to ```InsufficientAuthenticationException```

Comment: Hi @DhawalV , the filter that is used for authentication should normally be placed in front of the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` .I  suggest you can try to use `http.addFilterAfter(jwtAuthFilter),BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);` when `configure(HttpSecurity http)` such that it can be placed at the similar position of the built-in `BasicAuthenticationFilter`

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround for now I simply added my custom error from the `JwtAuthFilter` as a `request` attribute and retrieved it in the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`